# Ruby on Rails: Error al subir imágenes a Amazon S3 con paperclip y fog

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estoy utilizando las gemas de 'fog' y 'paperclip' para subir imágenes a s3, pero cada vez que lanzo la petición a mi API para guardar la imagen me lanza una advertencia en la terminal:

> [fog][WARNING] fog: followed redirect to s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com, connecting to the matching region will be more performant

y mi modelo está configurado así:

```
has_attached_file :avatar,
  :storage => :fog,
  :fog_credentials => {
                        :provider                 => 'AWS',
                        :aws_access_key_id        => access_key_id,
                        :aws_secret_access_key    => secret_access_key,
                        :region                   => 'eu-west-1',
                        :path_style               => true
                      },
    :fog_directory => "bucket",
    :fog_region    => 'eu-west-1'
```

No sé si el error se debe a que estoy enviando una imagen en base64 o algún error en la configuración de amazon s3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes de remover la opción `:fog_region`, ya la tiene especificada en `:fog_credentials`, con esto dejara de mostrar la advertencias.

ejemplo:

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
          :storage => :fog,
          :fog_credentials => {
            :provider => "AWS",
            :aws_access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
            :aws_secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
            :region => 'eu-west-1',
          },
          :fog_directory => ENV["S3_BUCKET_NAME"]
       }
     end
```

Comment: Solucionado! Muchas gracias.